# Graph returned an error: Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Been to all the links on on Stack for this and can't figure it out for the life of me.

I have a auth procedure for facebook on the following urls

/fb/auth

/fb/auth/callback

I have both in the Valid OAuth redirect URIs portion of the facebook app settings in advanced but I keep receiving the following error.

Graph returned an error: Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration

This was working yesterday and just stopped working today with no changes.

Comment: What platforms do you have set up for your app? Do you have an _app domain_ configured? And what what is the actual URL your are calling the login dialog from?

Comment: Just the web platform. and yes I do. So I'm running into an issue now where it only works if i specify that my redirect URI is http even though it's https. I'm also running into the issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31347341/the-state-param-from-the-url-and-session-do-not-match and am only able to fix it fixing the facebook src, which doesn't sound right

Comment: Well what is suggested there is not an actual “fix” of the issue, but just a complete negation of that security feature. As I commented there already, such problems are in most cases due to the PHP session not working correctly.

Answer (score 4):

if you using Facebook PHP SDK...

in callback script need change

```
$accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
```

to

```
$accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken('https://example.com/fb-callback.php');
```

where 'https://example.com/fb-callback.php' it's URI to your callback script

and add this URI to "Valid OAuth redirect URIs" to "Application configuration" on Facebook->My Apps-> Settings-> Advanced

Comment: that will teach me to follow the official getting started docs!  I was referring to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted.

Comment: Thank you so much! Saved the day.

Answer (score 0):

Try configure your URLs with a trailing slash in both Facebook app settings and the `redirect_uri` in your code.