# while using htaccess redirect facebook login is not working

Tags: php, facebook, .htaccess, redirect

when i tried to add htaccess redirect on my site facebook login which was working earlier stopped working..

the error it shows is

> Cross-site request forgery validation failed. The "state" param from the URL and session do not match.

here is rewrite code I've

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ apps.php?app_id=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ apps.php?app_id=$1&user_id=$2 [L]
```

**when I use the above rewrite code FACEBOOK LOGIN is not working if I there is any for loop/while loop in my script. With out loops this rewrite code and FACEBOOK LOGIN works perfectly.**

Comment: Have a look here and see if it helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31347341/the-state-param-from-the-url-and-session-do-not-match

Comment: no because I'm not having any issue before rewrite is applied

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

instead of

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Comment: add Options -MultiViews on the top before RewriteEngine On

Comment: no sir I've used 

Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.fbrackets\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://fbrackets.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ apps.php?app_id=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ apps.php?app_id=$1&user_id=$2 [L]


but still of no use

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have the reputation when I left the answer.

Comment: when I use the above rewrite code FACEBOOK LOGIN is not working if  I there is any for loop/while loop in my script. 
With out loops this rewrite code and FACEBOOK LOGIN works perfectly.